# MVC Model.Any System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

As in topic a faced with System.ArgumentNullException on View:

```
@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <h1 class="text-center">Nie ma żadnej storny!</h1>
}
```

I tried other options like (Model==null) but model is always null.. Or Model.Count() == 0, same problem, value cannot be 0.. Anyway please consider what i wrote. That what annoys me is i did it according to course and of course there wasn't any problem with run app..

When i removed this if i got error on non set object in

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {}
```

**View:**

```
    @model IEnumerable<CmsShop.Models.ViewModels.Pages.PageVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Strony";
}

<h2>Strony</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Dodaj Nową Stronę", "AddPage")
</p>

@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <h1 class="text-center">Nie ma żadnej storny!</h1>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Tytuł Strony
            </th>
            <th>
                Adres Strony
            </th>
            <th>
                Pasek Boczny
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Slug)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HasSideBar)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edycja", new { id=item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Szczegóły", new { id=item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Usuń", new { id=item.Id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CmsShop.Models.Data;
using CmsShop.Models.ViewModels.Pages;

namespace CmsShop.Controllers
{
    public class PagesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Admin/Pages
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // Deklaracja listy PageViewModel
            List<PageVM> pagesList;


            using (DB db = new DB()) //po wykonaniu wszystkie co jest w usingu, wyczyści swoje zasoby (dobra praktyka)
            {//inicjalizacja listy danych z bazy danych
                pagesList = db.Pages.ToArray().OrderBy(x => x.Sorting).Select(x => new PageVM(x)).ToList(); //automatyczne mapowanie z konstruktora argumentowego w PageVM
            }

            //zwracamy strony do widoku
            return View(pagesList);
        }

    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using CmsShop.Models.Data;

namespace CmsShop.Models.ViewModels.Pages
{
    public class PageVM
    {

        public PageVM()
        {

        }

        public PageVM(PageDTO row) //konstruktor przyjmujący wiersz bazy danych
        {
            Id = row.Id;
            Title = row.Title;
            Slug = row.Slug;
            Body = row.Body;
            Sorting = row.Sorting;
            HasSideBar = row.HasSideBar;
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50,MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "Tytuł Strony")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Adres Strony")]
        public string Slug { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(int.MaxValue, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "Zawartość Strony")]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public int Sorting { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Pasek Boczny")]
        public bool HasSideBar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, are you saying your page always enters the `@if (!Model.Any())` if? And you want it to show elements? If it is not showing elements is because `db.Pages.ToArray()` is not returning any elements there. Have you tried debugging? What does `db.Pages.ToArray()` do?

Comment: Thank you for response. I tried debugin but i even when i send request, it stop on Pages param, do not reach Index.

Comment: ToArray using a Pages method get all objects to table which i can sort later and transfer into list. If i understood correctly.I tried without ToArray but it's same result.

Comment: To test it out add some dummy data to your PageLists and don't call the db.Pages. And see if you can see teh dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing comes from null provided to the View in the return statement cause `pagesList` is not properly initialized.
Most probably you have no data in database, or for whatever reason fail to connect to it and list you're passing down the line remains null.

It is always a good practice to initialize your variables.

```
            // Deklaracja listy PageViewModel
            List<PageVM> pagesList = new List<PageVM>();
```

This will solve your null reference issue. However, most probably, you will not have anything displayed, but that is due to missing data in your db, or bad connection etc. (we cannot see what is done in DB()).

Also `ToArray()` can be ommited in call `db.Pages.ToArray()`. It makes no sense in that context and if it is part of the lecture, maybe consider another one.
`ToList()` is also not needed since your model is of type `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thank you for resposne, DB:

using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CmsShop.Models.Data
{
    public class DB:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<PageDTO> Pages { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Inicialize 
            List<PageVM> pagesList = new List<PageVM>();
Unfortunatley won't help me. I have one record in DB, i added it for test.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that way will be easier to understand a problem
Full Error:

```
CS1061: 'PageVM' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'PageVM' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)



M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml(15,13): error CS1061: 'PageVM' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'PageVM' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml(35,31): error CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'PageVM' because 'PageVM' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'
M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml(47,62): error CS0828: Cannot assign 'method group' to anonymous type property
M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml(48,68): error CS0828: Cannot assign 'method group' to anonymous type property
M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml(49,62): error CS0828: Cannot assign 'method group' to anonymous type property


Wiersz 1:    #pragma checksum "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml" "{ff1816ec-aa5e-4d10-87f7-6f4963833460}" "A311074B35D42046F94A4AA53D453318D0661EDF"
Wiersz 2:    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Wiersz 3:    // <auto-generated>
Wiersz 4:    //     Ten kod został wygenerowany przez narzędzie.
Wiersz 5:    //     Wersja wykonawcza:4.0.30319.42000
Wiersz 6:    //
Wiersz 7:    //     Zmiany w tym pliku mogą spowodować nieprawidłowe zachowanie i zostaną utracone, jeśli
Wiersz 8:    //     kod zostanie ponownie wygenerowany.
Wiersz 9:    // </auto-generated>
Wiersz 10:   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Wiersz 11:   
Wiersz 12:   namespace ASP {
Wiersz 13:       using System;
Wiersz 14:       using System.Collections.Generic;
Wiersz 15:       using System.IO;
Wiersz 16:       using System.Linq;
Wiersz 17:       using System.Net;
Wiersz 18:       using System.Web;
Wiersz 19:       using System.Web.Helpers;
Wiersz 20:       using System.Web.Security;
Wiersz 21:       using System.Web.UI;
Wiersz 22:       using System.Web.WebPages;
Wiersz 23:       using System.Web.Mvc;
Wiersz 24:       using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
Wiersz 25:       using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
Wiersz 26:       using System.Web.Optimization;
Wiersz 27:       using System.Web.Routing;
Wiersz 28:       using CmsShop;
Wiersz 29:       
Wiersz 30:       
Wiersz 31:       public class _Page_Views_Pages_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<CmsShop.Models.ViewModels.Pages.PageVM> {
Wiersz 32:           
Wiersz 33:   #line hidden
Wiersz 34:           
Wiersz 35:           public _Page_Views_Pages_Index_cshtml() {
Wiersz 36:           }
Wiersz 37:           
Wiersz 38:           protected ASP.global_asax ApplicationInstance {
Wiersz 39:               get {
Wiersz 40:                   return ((ASP.global_asax)(Context.ApplicationInstance));
Wiersz 41:               }
Wiersz 42:           }
Wiersz 43:           
Wiersz 44:           public override void Execute() {
Wiersz 45:               
Wiersz 46:               #line 3 "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Wiersz 47:     
Wiersz 48:       ViewBag.Title = "Strony";
Wiersz 49:   
Wiersz 50:               
Wiersz 51:               #line default
Wiersz 52:               #line hidden
Wiersz 53:   BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 85, 36, true);
Wiersz 54:   
Wiersz 55:   WriteLiteral("\r\n\r\n<h2>Strony</h2>\r\n\r\nModel.\r\n<p>\r\n");
Wiersz 56:   
Wiersz 57:   EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 85, 36, true);
Wiersz 58:   
Wiersz 59:   BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 121, 4, true);
Wiersz 60:   
Wiersz 61:   WriteLiteral("    ");
Wiersz 62:   
Wiersz 63:   EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 121, 4, true);
Wiersz 64:   
Wiersz 65:   BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 126, 47, false);
Wiersz 66:   
Wiersz 67:               
Wiersz 68:               #line 11 "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Wiersz 69:   Write(Html.ActionLink("Dodaj Nową Stronę", "AddPage"));
Wiersz 70:   
Wiersz 71:               
Wiersz 72:               #line default
Wiersz 73:               #line hidden
Wiersz 74:   EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 126, 47, false);
Wiersz 75:   
Wiersz 76:   BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 173, 12, true);
Wiersz 77:   
Wiersz 78:   WriteLiteral("\r\n</p>\r\n\r\n\r\n");
Wiersz 79:   
Wiersz 80:   EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 173, 12, true);
Wiersz 81:   
Wiersz 82:               
Wiersz 83:               #line 15 "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Wiersz 84:    if (!Model.Any())
Wiersz 85:   {
Wiersz 86:   
Wiersz 87:               
Wiersz 88:               #line default
Wiersz 89:               #line hidden
Wiersz 90:   BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 208, 7, true);
Wiersz 91:   
Wiersz 92:   WriteLiteral("    <h1");
Wiersz 93:   
Wiersz 94:   EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 208, 7, true);
Wiersz 95:   
Wiersz 96:   BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 215, 20, true);
Wiersz 97:   
Wiersz 98:   WriteLiteral(" class=\"text-center\"");
Wiersz 99:   
Wiersz 100:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 215, 20, true);
Wiersz 101:  
Wiersz 102:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 235, 29, true);
Wiersz 103:  
Wiersz 104:  WriteLiteral(">Nie ma żadnej strony!</h1>\r\n");
Wiersz 105:  
Wiersz 106:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 235, 29, true);
Wiersz 107:  
Wiersz 108:              
Wiersz 109:              #line 18 "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Wiersz 110:  }
Wiersz 111:  else
Wiersz 112:  {
Wiersz 113:  
Wiersz 114:              
Wiersz 115:              #line default
Wiersz 116:              #line hidden
Wiersz 117:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 276, 10, true);
Wiersz 118:  
Wiersz 119:  WriteLiteral("    <table");
Wiersz 120:  
Wiersz 121:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 276, 10, true);
Wiersz 122:  
Wiersz 123:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 286, 14, true);
Wiersz 124:  
Wiersz 125:  WriteLiteral(" class=\"table\"");
Wiersz 126:  
Wiersz 127:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 286, 14, true);
Wiersz 128:  
Wiersz 129:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 300, 258, true);
Wiersz 130:  
Wiersz 131:  WriteLiteral(@">
Wiersz 132:          <tr>
Wiersz 133:              <th>
Wiersz 134:                  Tytuł Strony
Wiersz 135:              </th>
Wiersz 136:              <th>
Wiersz 137:                  Adres Strony
Wiersz 138:              </th>
Wiersz 139:              <th>
Wiersz 140:                  Pasek Boczny
Wiersz 141:              </th>
Wiersz 142:              <th></th>
Wiersz 143:          </tr>
Wiersz 144:  
Wiersz 145:  ");
Wiersz 146:  
Wiersz 147:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 300, 258, true);
Wiersz 148:  
Wiersz 149:              
Wiersz 150:              #line 35 "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Wiersz 151:          
Wiersz 152:              
Wiersz 153:              #line default
Wiersz 154:              #line hidden
Wiersz 155:              
Wiersz 156:              #line 35 "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Wiersz 157:           foreach (var item in Model) {
Wiersz 158:  
Wiersz 159:              
Wiersz 160:              #line default
Wiersz 161:              #line hidden
Wiersz 162:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 598, 40, true);
Wiersz 163:  
Wiersz 164:  WriteLiteral("            <tr>\r\n                <td>\r\n");
Wiersz 165:  
Wiersz 166:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 598, 40, true);
Wiersz 167:  
Wiersz 168:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 638, 20, true);
Wiersz 169:  
Wiersz 170:  WriteLiteral("                    ");
Wiersz 171:  
Wiersz 172:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 638, 20, true);
Wiersz 173:  
Wiersz 174:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 659, 40, false);
Wiersz 175:  
Wiersz 176:              
Wiersz 177:              #line 38 "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Wiersz 178:                 Write(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title));
Wiersz 179:  
Wiersz 180:              
Wiersz 181:              #line default
Wiersz 182:              #line hidden
Wiersz 183:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 659, 40, false);
Wiersz 184:  
Wiersz 185:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 699, 47, true);
Wiersz 186:  
Wiersz 187:  WriteLiteral("\r\n                </td>\r\n                <td>\r\n");
Wiersz 188:  
Wiersz 189:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 699, 47, true);
Wiersz 190:  
Wiersz 191:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 746, 20, true);
Wiersz 192:  
Wiersz 193:  WriteLiteral("                    ");
Wiersz 194:  
Wiersz 195:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 746, 20, true);
Wiersz 196:  
Wiersz 197:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 767, 39, false);
Wiersz 198:  
Wiersz 199:              
Wiersz 200:              #line 41 "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Wiersz 201:                 Write(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Slug));
Wiersz 202:  
Wiersz 203:              
Wiersz 204:              #line default
Wiersz 205:              #line hidden
Wiersz 206:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 767, 39, false);
Wiersz 207:  
Wiersz 208:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 806, 47, true);
Wiersz 209:  
Wiersz 210:  WriteLiteral("\r\n                </td>\r\n                <td>\r\n");
Wiersz 211:  
Wiersz 212:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 806, 47, true);
Wiersz 213:  
Wiersz 214:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 853, 20, true);
Wiersz 215:  
Wiersz 216:  WriteLiteral("                    ");
Wiersz 217:  
Wiersz 218:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 853, 20, true);
Wiersz 219:  
Wiersz 220:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 874, 45, false);
Wiersz 221:  
Wiersz 222:              
Wiersz 223:              #line 44 "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Wiersz 224:                 Write(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HasSideBar));
Wiersz 225:  
Wiersz 226:              
Wiersz 227:              #line default
Wiersz 228:              #line hidden
Wiersz 229:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 874, 45, false);
Wiersz 230:  
Wiersz 231:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 919, 47, true);
Wiersz 232:  
Wiersz 233:  WriteLiteral("\r\n                </td>\r\n                <td>\r\n");
Wiersz 234:  
Wiersz 235:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 919, 47, true);
Wiersz 236:  
Wiersz 237:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 966, 20, true);
Wiersz 238:  
Wiersz 239:  WriteLiteral("                    ");
Wiersz 240:  
Wiersz 241:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 966, 20, true);
Wiersz 242:  
Wiersz 243:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 987, 53, false);
Wiersz 244:  
Wiersz 245:              
Wiersz 246:              #line 47 "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Wiersz 247:                 Write(Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edycja", new { id=item.Id }));
Wiersz 248:  
Wiersz 249:              
Wiersz 250:              #line default
Wiersz 251:              #line hidden
Wiersz 252:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 987, 53, false);
Wiersz 253:  
Wiersz 254:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1040, 4, true);
Wiersz 255:  
Wiersz 256:  WriteLiteral(" |\r\n");
Wiersz 257:  
Wiersz 258:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1040, 4, true);
Wiersz 259:  
Wiersz 260:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1044, 20, true);
Wiersz 261:  
Wiersz 262:  WriteLiteral("                    ");
Wiersz 263:  
Wiersz 264:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1044, 20, true);
Wiersz 265:  
Wiersz 266:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1065, 59, false);
Wiersz 267:  
Wiersz 268:              
Wiersz 269:              #line 48 "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Wiersz 270:                 Write(Html.ActionLink("Details", "Szczegóły", new { id=item.Id }));
Wiersz 271:  
Wiersz 272:              
Wiersz 273:              #line default
Wiersz 274:              #line hidden
Wiersz 275:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1065, 59, false);
Wiersz 276:  
Wiersz 277:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1124, 4, true);
Wiersz 278:  
Wiersz 279:  WriteLiteral(" |\r\n");
Wiersz 280:  
Wiersz 281:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1124, 4, true);
Wiersz 282:  
Wiersz 283:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1128, 20, true);
Wiersz 284:  
Wiersz 285:  WriteLiteral("                    ");
Wiersz 286:  
Wiersz 287:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1128, 20, true);
Wiersz 288:  
Wiersz 289:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1149, 53, false);
Wiersz 290:  
Wiersz 291:              
Wiersz 292:              #line 49 "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Wiersz 293:                 Write(Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Usuń", new { id=item.Id }));
Wiersz 294:  
Wiersz 295:              
Wiersz 296:              #line default
Wiersz 297:              #line hidden
Wiersz 298:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1149, 53, false);
Wiersz 299:  
Wiersz 300:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1202, 44, true);
Wiersz 301:  
Wiersz 302:  WriteLiteral("\r\n                </td>\r\n            </tr>\r\n");
Wiersz 303:  
Wiersz 304:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1202, 44, true);
Wiersz 305:  
Wiersz 306:              
Wiersz 307:              #line 52 "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Wiersz 308:          }
Wiersz 309:  
Wiersz 310:              
Wiersz 311:              #line default
Wiersz 312:              #line hidden
Wiersz 313:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1257, 16, true);
Wiersz 314:  
Wiersz 315:  WriteLiteral("\r\n    </table>\r\n");
Wiersz 316:  
Wiersz 317:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1257, 16, true);
Wiersz 318:  
Wiersz 319:              
Wiersz 320:              #line 55 "M:\Google Drive\Projekty do nauki\CMS_Shop\CmsShop\CmsShop\Views\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Wiersz 321:  }
Wiersz 322:  
Wiersz 323:              
Wiersz 324:              #line default
Wiersz 325:              #line hidden
Wiersz 326:  BeginContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1276, 4, true);
Wiersz 327:  
Wiersz 328:  WriteLiteral("\r\n\r\n");
Wiersz 329:  
Wiersz 330:  EndContext("~/Views/Pages/Index.cshtml", 1276, 4, true);
Wiersz 331:  
Wiersz 332:          }
Wiersz 333:      }
Wiersz 334:  }
Wiersz 335:
```

DB Context:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CmsShop.Models.Data
{
    public class DB:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<PageDTO> Pages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PageDTO:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace CmsShop.Models.Data
{
    [Table("tblPages")]
    public class PageDTO
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public int Sorting { get; set; }
        public bool HasSideBar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding `@using System.Linq; ` at the top of the view (above model definition, for example).